# Include Javascript file in another javascript file and Loading

Tags: javascript, html

I trying to make one path.js file by which all js files in different folders get paths from. Obiviosuly I am making a big blunders in my code so how can i do that.

For Example the folder structure is like this:

```
ProjectFolder
-- index.html
-- paths.js
-- newFolder
     -- main.js
     -- main1.js
```

Here is my code:

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="main/main.js"></script>
   <script>
      alert(dis);
   </script>    
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../path.js"> </script>
var dis = path;
```

paths.js

```
var path = "PATH";
var path2 = "PATH2";
```

Comment: use `requirejs.org` lib

Comment: You can't write html in a js file. You are looking for module loader like requirejs or webpack.

Comment: I think [you'll really love this](http://requirejs.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just include paths.js in your html.file.as a link. The other js files will then see it's variables.